# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Partial view not appearing when referenced from Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I am currently trying to reference a partial called _SubNavigation from the Index.cshtml file located in Areas/Applications/Views/Applications

However, when I load up the page, its not appearing. When I open it up in inspect, it just shows the link

```
<partial name="~/Views/Shared/Navigation/_SubNavigation.cshtml" />
```

For some reason the layout is getting loaded but thats located in the same area as my SubNavigation file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `partial`, it is using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`, here are two options for you:

- Change to use `@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/Navigation/_SubNavigation.cshtml")`
- If you prefer `partial` tag, you need to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` by copying `_ViewImports.cshtml` from `Views Folder` to your `Areas Folder`

Comment: "by copying _ViewImports.cshtml from Views Folder to your Areas Folder" that part was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hope this solution helped:

```
@Html.Partial("_SubNavigation", "[... Data to partial ...]")
```

**Note:** the `@` mark before `Html` is important even inside `@{ ... }` code block.